# "Solve $f’=f$ where $f$ never vanishes"; what do they mean by "vanish"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> “Let us attempt to solve $f’=f$ where $f$ never vanishes.”

What do they mean by this? I’m guessing they don’t want $f$ to turn to the zero function, but even then, we’d need a constant $C\neq 0$, such that $C’=0\neq C$, for $f$ to 'vanish'... But then the equation isn't satisfied - so they must have meant something else, but I wouldn't know what.

Comment: There is no $x$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM So if a function is zero at $x$, that means the function vanishes at $x$?

Comment: @ShaVuklia Yes, they're interchangeable.

Comment: @Ian Alright, cool, thanks!

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Sounds like your comment is an acceptable answer.  Care to write it as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we proceed to find the solution, we usually do something like:

$$\frac{df}{dx} = f \mbox{ so that } \frac{df}{f} = dx,$$

and then integrate.  The condition that $f$ never vanishes (is never $0$) is needed because we want to divide by $f$.

Comment: Oh, you're right! Later on they rewrite it as $\frac{f'}{f}=1$, so the restriction on $f$ makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

By "$f$ never vanishes", it should be understood that for all $x$, $f(x)\neq 0$.